# Trying to update a database entry but a new one is added

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

So here's the short run down:
My system has two types of users: company and student.
The company posts a job, the student applies (a new entry is added to the application database table), the company selects the application and offers the job to the student, the site takes him to the contract page, where the company can see how the contract looks like and where the student's CPR (SSN) would go. He or she fills out the company's CVR (company SSN) and their first name and last name and clicks submit. This creates a new entry in the contract database table. So far so good.

Here is the Contract.cs model class:

```
namespace Leepio.Models
{
    public class Contract { 
        public int ContractId { get; set; }
        public string StudentId { get; set; }
        public string CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string CVR { get; set; }
        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
        public bool IsSigned { get; set; }
        public string StudentSigningDate { get; set; }
        public string CompanySigningDate { get; set; }
        public string RepFirstName { get; set; }
        public string RepLastName { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Student { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Company { get; set; }
        public virtual Application Application { get; set; }


    }
```

Everything is filled at this point except two fields: the IsSigned field (should turn to true when the student accepts and submits) and StudentSigningDate, which is just the date in form of a string of the day the student accepts).
Now the student gets an email and he or she goes to the link where they can see a preview of the contract and a textbox where the CPR is typed in and then the submit button.

Now here is where the problem starts.

this is the method for the submit button:

```
 public ActionResult SendMailAsAStudent(string studentId, string companyId, int applicationId, string companyCVR, string studentCPR)
        {
            var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            var student = manager.FindById(studentId);
            var company = manager.FindById(companyId);
            var application = db.Applications.Find(applicationId);
            var contractobj = db.Contracts.Find(applicationId);
            Project projectobj = db.Projects.Find(application.ProjectId);


            var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
            myMessage.From = new MailAddress("info@leepio.dk");
            myMessage.AddTo(student.Email);
            myMessage.AddTo(company.Email);
            myMessage.Subject ="The contract for " + projectobj.Title + " is signed!";
            myMessage.Html = "Here is the final contract";


            LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();

            localReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Contracts/Contract.rdlc");
            ReportParameter cvrParameter = new ReportParameter("cvrParameter", companyCVR);
            ReportParameter companyNameParameter = new ReportParameter("companyNameParameter", company.CompanyName);
            ReportParameter companyAddressParameter = new ReportParameter("companyAddressParameter", company.Address);
            ReportParameter companyCityParameter = new ReportParameter("companyCityParameter", company.City);
            ReportParameter studentCityParameter = new ReportParameter("studentCityParameter", student.City);
            ReportParameter studentNameParameter = new ReportParameter("studentNameParameter", student.FirstName+" "+student.LastName);
            ReportParameter studentAddressParameter = new ReportParameter("studentAddressParameter", student.Address);
            ReportParameter studentZipCodeParameter = new ReportParameter("studentZipCodeParameter", student.ZipCode);
            ReportParameter jobStartDateParameter = new ReportParameter("jobStartDateParameter", projectobj.StartDate);
            ReportParameter jobEndDateParameter = new ReportParameter("jobEndDateParameter", projectobj.EndDate);
            ReportParameter jobDescriptionParameter = new ReportParameter("jobDescriptionParameter", projectobj.Description);
            ReportParameter jobHoursPerWeekParameter = new ReportParameter("jobHoursPerWeekParameter", projectobj.HoursPerWeek.ToString());
            ReportParameter jobHourlyRateParameter = new ReportParameter("jobHourlyRateParameter", projectobj.HourlyRate.ToString());
            ReportParameter cprParameter = new ReportParameter("cprParameter", studentCPR);
            ReportParameter studentSignDateParameter = new ReportParameter("studentSignDateParameter", DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            ReportParameter companySignDateParameter = new ReportParameter("companySignDateParameter", contractobj.CompanySigningDate);
            ReportParameter companyRepNameParameter = new ReportParameter("companyRepNameParameter", contractobj.RepFirstName +" "+contractobj.RepLastName);
            ReportParameter projectWorkFromParameter = new ReportParameter("projectWorkFromParameter", projectobj.WorkFrom);


            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { cprParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { cvrParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { companyNameParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { companyAddressParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { studentNameParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { studentAddressParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { studentZipCodeParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { jobStartDateParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { jobEndDateParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { jobDescriptionParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { jobHoursPerWeekParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { jobHourlyRateParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { studentSignDateParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { companySignDateParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { companyRepNameParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { projectWorkFromParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { companyCityParameter });
            localReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { studentCityParameter });

            string reportType = "PDF";
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string fileNameExtension = "pdf";
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streams;
            var renderedBytes = localReport.Render(reportType, "", out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attatchment; filename=Contract." + fileNameExtension);

           MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(renderedBytes);
           myMessage.AddAttachment(stream, "Contract.pdf");


            var apiKey = "removed for this post";
            var transportWeb = new Web(apiKey);
            transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);

            Contract contract = db.Contracts.Find(contractobj.ContractId);

            contract.IsSigned = true;
            contract.StudentSigningDate = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");



            //db.Contracts.Add(contract);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Projects");
        }
```

Then this happens:

[image]

The entry is added as I wanted it to: isSigned is false and the student signing date is not yet filled in.
When it does get filled in, it creates another entry in the database, with the company's signing date, first name and last name to false!

What causes this? I've commented out the db.Contracs.Add(contract), I find the contract I needed by applicationId since that would be the unique identifier. What am I doing wrong? I want to be able to add the student sign in date and change the IsSigned bool to true.
Note that the student CPR is not stored in the database, the "20" is the application's ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution:

I now pass the contractId as a parameter instead of all the ones I had before:

```
public ActionResult SendMailAsAStudent(int contractId, string studentCPR)
```

then I just retrieve the contract as so:

```
Contract contract = db.Contracts.Find(contractId);
```

Changed all the retrieving process for the parameters:

```
 ReportParameter cvrParameter = new ReportParameter("cvrParameter", contract.CVR);
            ReportParameter companyNameParameter = new ReportParameter("companyNameParameter", contract.Company.CompanyName);
            ReportParameter companyAddressParameter = new ReportParameter("companyAddressParameter", contract.Company.Address);
            ReportParameter companyCityParameter = new ReportParameter("companyCityParameter", contract.Company.City);
            ReportParameter studentCityParameter = new ReportParameter("studentCityParameter", contract.Student.City);
            ReportParameter studentNameParameter = new ReportParameter("studentNameParameter", contract.Student.FirstName+" "+ contract.Student.LastName);
            ReportParameter studentAddressParameter = new ReportParameter("studentAddressParameter", contract.Student.Address);
            ReportParameter studentZipCodeParameter = new ReportParameter("studentZipCodeParameter", contract.Student.ZipCode);
            ReportParameter jobStartDateParameter = new ReportParameter("jobStartDateParameter", contract.Application.Project.StartDate);
            ReportParameter jobEndDateParameter = new ReportParameter("jobEndDateParameter", contract.Application.Project.EndDate);
            ReportParameter jobDescriptionParameter = new ReportParameter("jobDescriptionParameter", contract.Application.Project.Description);
            ReportParameter jobHoursPerWeekParameter = new ReportParameter("jobHoursPerWeekParameter", contract.Application.Project.HoursPerWeek.ToString());
            ReportParameter jobHourlyRateParameter = new ReportParameter("jobHourlyRateParameter", contract.Application.Project.HourlyRate.ToString());
            ReportParameter cprParameter = new ReportParameter("cprParameter", studentCPR);
            ReportParameter studentSignDateParameter = new ReportParameter("studentSignDateParameter", DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            ReportParameter companySignDateParameter = new ReportParameter("companySignDateParameter", contract.CompanySigningDate);
            ReportParameter companyRepNameParameter = new ReportParameter("companyRepNameParameter", contract.RepFirstName +" "+contract.RepLastName);
            ReportParameter projectWorkFromParameter = new ReportParameter("projectWorkFromParameter", contract.Application.Project.WorkFrom);
```

This also fixed my other problem with the parameter from my other post.
[An attempt was made to set a report parameter 'studentSignDateParameter' that is not defined in this report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484790/an-attempt-was-made-to-set-a-report-parameter-studentsigndateparameter-that-is)